# What is the difference between 'suck', 'suck at', and 'suck on'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can those be used interchangeably? These are three examples from the Longman dictionary. I see no essential difference between the cases so I assume you can use any option you like without any reservations (no preposition, 'at', or 'on'). Am I right?

> a baby **sucking at** its mother’s breast
>
> Don’t **suck** your thumb, dear.
>
> a picture of Lara **sucking on** a lollipop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *literal* and most common meaning of "suck" is to *draw into the mouth by contracting the muscles of the lips and mouth to make a partial vacuum*. This is the definition that applies in all of your examples.

"Suck" and "suck on" are pretty much interchangeable, and in your latter 2 examples, either could work:

> Don't suck your thumb / Don't suck *on* your thumb.
>
> Sucking a lollipop / sucking *on* a lollipop.

(although "sucking your thumb" is probably the most idiomatic in that example)

However, when it comes to a *baby* feeding, it is idiomatic to say "sucking *at* the breast", because it is as much a statement of their location and position as it is what they have in their mouth. It may even be considered an abbreviation of "*suckling*", which, as a verb, means *to feed (a baby or young animal) from the breast or teat*.

As an aside, the expression "suck *at*" something is also a modern colloquialism meaning that you are "*bad at*", or "*not adept*" at something.

Comment: You can also suck something that is enclosed in your mouth, like a boiled sweet (hard candy if you're American).